# JavaMail Export Mails to defined folder on disk

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In asp.net it is possible to pick a folder on disk and save all the outgoing emails in this specified folder for debugging purpose.

Is there a similar configuration possible in java mail?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the program that does that, but JavaMail provides the APIs to allow you to write a program that reads messages from a folder and saves them to local disk.  See the [JavaMail sample programs](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).